# Hibernate: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, spring-mvc, db2

I am using DB2 for my application. I run some insertion script after creating database. That insertion script generates records in table with id's given in insertion script.

Suppose for abc table insertion script creates a record with id = 3. As id’s are set to auto generated in hibernate so while saving third record from application I got exception.

```
        Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.DuplicateKeyException: One or
 more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign
 key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid
 because the primary key, unique constraint or unique
 index identified by "1" constrains table
```

I am using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

What `strategy = GenerationType` I should use to overcome this problem.

Comment: you must clear database after insert this rule

Comment: @SjB After insert which rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing works except this query.

```
alter table TABLE_NAME alter column ID set GENERATED BY DEFAULT RESTART WITH 10000;
```

DB2 should choose available ID itself but not doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with certain Databases and Hibernate when you use GenerationType.IDENTITY. Try using a sequence and explicitlly configure everything for it:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="department_sequence", allocationSize=100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DEPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
protected Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For DB2 `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If ids are provided in file then you don't need `@GeneratedValue` at all as there is no id to generate. And make sure to clean database as @SjB suggested.

Also, without knowing much about DB2, the error message suggests that there may be other violation than just duplicate id on insert. Are there any foreign keys involved?